# Values in my dataframe are not the same as ones in my database table(R and MySQL))

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, twitter

I am getting tweet_id from a table in my database and storing them in a dataframe in r. The problem is that the tweet_id values are not being added correctly in dataframe.

snapshot of my table:

[image]

snapshot of my dataframe in rstudio:

[image]

As you can see there is no tweet_id = '882100387989291008'(3rd value in my dataframe) in my database table

my Rscript file:

```
#connecting with db
#myDB = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "root", password = "F33mtHaDD", dbname = "dashboard", host= "127.0.0.1", port="8889")

myDB =dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "root", password ="F33mtHaDD", dbname = "dashboard")


options(scipen=10)
options()$scipen

#running a query and retriving data and saving it in a object
rs = dbSendQuery(myDB, "SELECT tweet_id, sentiment, text FROM dashboard.sen_tweets_twitter WHERE text <> '';")

#getting the result. The function fetch() saves the result in a dataframe
datafetd = fetch(rs, n=-1)


#removing extra whitespaces
#new = stripWhitespace(datafetd$text)
#dataafterclean =data.frame(new)

#converts into one single string
review_text = paste(datafetd$text)
review_id = paste(datafetd$tweet_id)

print(review_id)

rm(tm_tdm)

#find the number of data
tweets_num = length(review_text)


#Disconnect connections
dbdisconnect = lapply(dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)

#checking if all connection has been closed
dbListConnections(MySQL())
```

The values in my database are the correct ones.How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to select missing record by id?

Comment: @MichaelO.  Yes. I tried selecting the records for tweet_id=882100387989291008 in mysql database and it gave me 0 result.

Comment: But is `tweet_id` a number or a string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Its datatype is int(30)

Comment: Try to use not `tweet_id` but `ID` (9775) for selecting

Comment: Maybe those IDs are being truncated.  You could use `BIGINT` instead.

Comment: @Michael O. Okay i will try it with ID

Comment: @Michael O. It worked when i used ID. Thanks.

Comment: @R.Haroon Maybe those Twitter IDs are being truncated.  You should look into this.

Comment: @Michael O. truncated where? when i am getting them into the dataframe?

Comment: @Michael O Btw, tweet_id is the twitter id of a tweet which i am getting from the twitter api. According to the documentation the tweet_id datatype is int64

Answer (score 1):

Database tables represent unordered sets of data.  In your table snapshot, it appears that the records are sorted by `ID` in ascending order.  I postulate that all the data did in fact make it into your data frame, but that data frame has a different order than what you showed when querying your table.  To confirm this, you can try sorting the data frame ascending on the `ID`:

```
datafetd[with(datafetd, order(ID)), ]
```

Comment: nice! how is it different from `setorder(datafetd,ID)`?